# React native Linking not passing paramethers

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am using react native [linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) to create a short "Share" button link:

```
export async function buildShortLink(userId) {
  const redirectUrl = Linking.createURL('myAppName.app/user', {
    queryParams: { userId: userId },
  });
  return redirectUrl;
}
```

And the url looks like the following: `https://myAppName.app/user?userId=someRandomUserId` which is fine.

Then on my `App.js` I have added the following listener:

```
const handleDeepLink = (url)=>{
      let newURL = Linking.parse(url.url);
      console.log(newURL);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const urlListener = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleDeepLink);
        return () => {
          urlListener.remove();
        };
    }, []);
```

However, when I click on the above link (`https://myAppName.app/user?userId=someRandomUserId`) it does redirect me to the app, however, the url, which I receive is the following: `https://myAppName.app/user`, that is I don't receive any parameters.

Maybe worth mentioning that I am testing on android and my project is built on expo. I created eas build and installed it on my phone. The only warning I had on the console (and which I fixed) was with respect to the `scheme` property in my `package.json` file

```
"expo": {
    "name": "some name",
    "slug": "not-relevant",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    ...
    "scheme": "https",
     ...
```

Can someone please advise how to take those parameters?